# How can I iterate a list of data using 2D list in python?

Tags: python

I want to create a variable called containing a 2D (nested) list of 2 rows and 3 columns literal containing the values like this:

```
3    14   67 
13   24   19
```

the code I have now is sth like this but the outcome doesn't give me the outcome I want:

```py
for row in range(2):
    new_list = []
    for col in range(3):
        new_list.append(a_list)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: move `new_list` outside of the loop

Comment: and what is `a_list`?

Comment: a_list is the variable name I assigned*

Comment: a_list = [3, 14, 67, 13, 24, 19]

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code:

```
a_list = [3, 14, 67, 13, 24, 19] 
new_list = []
new_list += [a_list[0:3]]
new_list += [a_list[3:6]]
```

Comment: @cabbage_corgi you should try to write something more generic. This approach would not work for lists of other lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two-fold, you need to instantiate the correct number of lists to hold your elements; and you also need to pull elements from `a_list` in order.

You need to accumulate the elements of `a_list` into "rows" and you separately need to accumulate those rows into your outer list so that you end up with the structure:

```
[[3, 14, 67], [13, 24, 19]]
```

First, initialize an `outer_list` outside the loops. Then on each iteration of the outer loop, initialize an empty `row` list. Append the items from `a_list` to `row` in the inner loop. Then append `row` to the outer list at the end of the inner loop:

```py
a_list = [3, 14, 67, 13, 24, 19]

num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

# Make sure that num_rows * num_cols is equal to the length of the original list!

outer_list = []
for i in range(num_rows):
    row = []
    for j in range(num_cols):
        # row.append() <- grab the appropriate element from a_list
    outer_list.append(row)
```

I've left the hard part up to you, which is to figure out how to get an index using `i` and `j` that can access each element in `a_list` in order.

An easier approach would be to turn `a_list` into an iterator and repeatedly call `next()` on it, which negates the need for any tricky indexing. However, you should attempt to figure out how to index into `a_list` first before moving on so that you can get a decent understanding of how to work with lists.